# How to make a list comparison in groovy?

Tags: groovy

I want to perform a comparison between a list of location ids and one location id. Virtually I want to say if value `'000000'` should be displayed in each instance of the list of location ids `[000000, 000000, 000000, 000000, 000000]`. I can get it working for one instance for the list but how can I check all instances? At the moment it is checking one instance but I require the whole list to be checked.

Below is the groovy code:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper 
def response = messageExchange.response.responseContent
def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(response)

def location_id = json.reviews.location_id
assert location_id != null
def location_id_response = location_id[0].toString()
def location_id_request = messageExchange.modelItem.testStep.testCase.getPropertyValue("locationid")
assert location_id_response == location_id_request

log.info location_id_request
log.info location_id_response
log.info location_id
```

Below is the log information:

```
log.info location_id_request = '000000'
log.info location_id_response = '000000'
log.info location_id = [000000, 000000, 000000, 000000, 000000]
```

Virtually `location_id_response[0]` is picking the first value from the list, but I want all values from the list with `location_id_request`being compared to each value in the list, not just the first value. If I remove the '0' from [0], it throws an array error.

Comment: Why did you spam 3 different language tags? This question is about Groovy only, isn't it?

Comment: I thought that because groovy is similar to java and javascript that maybe it could be related

Comment: Groovy is similar to JavaScript?? That's news to me. If anything it's similar to Ruby

Comment: This question is unclear. You show what the result is, but not what you expect.

Comment: "groovy is similar to java and javascript" Java is not similar to Javascript http://javascriptisnotjava.io/ But most Java code is compilable by groovy. So this is not a problem to tag with both. Stop tagging questions with soapui also, you may be using it, but it is not relevant or even mentioned in the questions.

Comment: [Java is to JavaScript as ham is to hamster.](http://javascriptisnotjava.io/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need

```
assert location_id.every { it == location_id_request }
```

Or

```
assert location_id == [location_id_request] * location_id.size()
```

Or

```
assert location_id.distinct() == [location_id_request]
```

Or

```
assert location_id.distinct().with { it.head() == location_id_request && it.size() == 1 }
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks Tim

Comment: Except the last one probably allows for other elements existing in the list, unless you also verify size=1